# ¿Cómo saber en qué columna encontró el resultado de mi consulta WHERE ... OR ...?

Tags: php, php7

Aquí estoy haciendo una consulta buscando un resultado validando si el **email** está como autor o como destinatario, entonces me gustaría saber en qué columna lo encontró, si en *mess_by* o en *mess_destined*

```php
$get_author = $ken_get['email'];

$prueba = mysqli_query($bass,"SELECT * FROM $author WHERE mess_by = '$get_author' OR mess_destined = '$get_author' AND mess_accepted = 'true'");
```

Comment: Con SELECT * estás recuperando el registro entero, así que sólo tienes que mirar en el mismo el valor de mess_by y mess_destined. Otra cosa, agrupa entre paréntesis las condiciones que estás uniendo con OR, para que no se te mezcle la cosa con el AND. No te pongo esto como una respuesta porque tendría que incluir el código de cómo hacerlo, y prefiero que hagas tú el esfuerzo y aprendas un poco por el camino.

Comment: He añadido una respuesta detallada haciendo referencia a algo de lo que menciona @JoséCarlosPHP; veo que tu pregunta ha recibido un **voto negativo** aunque sinceramente no creo que lo merezca. Échale un ojo y espero haberte ayudado amigo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Observación 1

Noto que dices que estás buscando **un resultado**, pero al ejecutar tu **query** estas trayendo todos los resultados coincidentes con tu consulta.

Entonces para traer solo un resultados debes ejecutar algo como:

```sql
SELECT * FROM $author WHERE mess_by = '$get_author' OR mess_destined = '$get_author' AND mess_accepted = 'true' LIMIT 1;
```

##### Observación 2

Creo que tu consulta está buscando un registro que coincida con alguna de las siguientes condiciones:

- *mess_by* = `$get_author` **y** *mees_accepted* = `'true'`
- *mess_destined* = `$get_author` **y** *mees_accepted* = `'true'`

Entonces deberías cambiar tu **query** a algo como:

```sql
SELECT * FROM $author WHERE (mess_by = '$get_author' OR mess_destined = '$get_author') AND mess_accepted = 'true' LIMIT 1;
```

Agrupando la primera condición con paréntesis `(...)`. En caso de estar equivocado con esta observación, por favor ignorala.

---

Para saber si esta coincidencia la encontraste en **mess_by** o en **mess_destined**, solo debes pasar tu consulta a un **array asociativo** y comparar la columna:

```php
$get_author = $ken_get['email'];

$prueba = mysqli_query($bass,"SELECT * FROM $author WHERE (mess_by = '$get_author' OR mess_destined = '$get_author') AND mess_accepted = 'true' LIMIT 1");

$prueba = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prueba);

if( $prueba['mess_by'] == $get_author ) {
   echo 'encontrado en mess_by';
}
else if( $prueba['mess_destined'] == $get_author ) {
   echo 'encontrado en mess_destined';
}
```

Gracias a la función [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc) puedes pasar tu resultado a un **array asociativo**

##### NOTA

Ten mucho cuidado, tu código puede ser sensible a [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), si estos datos provienen por ejemplo desde el cliente.

Para ayudarte con esto puedes usar [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string) o prepared statements.